# Japanese Input Ubuntu 18.04 Applications installed via Snap

Tags: snap, japanese, mozc

I have re-installed Ubuntu 18.04 and did all the necessary steps to install Japanese (Mosz).

On this window, I can use it 日本語 but on Skype application I cannot. (I could before). On Google Docs I also cannot (I haven't tried it before). On Telegram Desktop App I cannot (I could before).

It seems to be the case on the applications that I have installed via snap.

Does anyone have a clue what I could do to being able to use the Japanese Mosz on those snap-installed applications as well?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I have no problem with `ibus-mozc` on 16.04 18.04 and 20.04 LTS(s). When you can type here, it is also available to type in Skype or other Japanese support applications. Perhaps you should open `Settings > Language Support` and confirm the necessary packages and settings are complete.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just found out that it is not working on Telegram Desktop either. I think it is related to the applications that I have installed using snap? I am still researching since it is yet not working

Comment: As a momentarily fix I have completely removed snap (and all the installed applications that came with it) and re-installed them using -deb packages. Now it seems to be working again. I could type with mozc on skype.

Answer (score 0):

## Possible solution

To try to resolve your question with [IBUS](https://github.com/ibus/ibus) IMF and [MOZC](https://github.com/google/mozc) IME, you need to re-switch the input method for each opened window.

Or you can set the configuration [to switch the input method for all opened windows at one time](https://moritzmolch.com/2404) by:

1. Gnome `system settings`
2. `Region & Language` side-menu
3. `options` button.
4. Switch:

   - from: `Allow different sources for each window` radio-button;
   - to: `Use the same source for all windows` radio-button.

[image: gnome configuration]

With that, all opened windows will use your selected input method.

## Context

About it be a snap specific problem, **It seems to be a bug not resolved**.

I searched at [ibus](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues?q=snap), [mozc](https://github.com/google/mozc/issues?q=snap) issue trackers. Yet, I searched at Snapcraft issue tracker too, specifically: an [old discussion](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cant-use-input-method-in-snap-apps/4712/52), about [Skype](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/ibus-doesnt-work-with-skype-snap-on-20-04/17279), about [mozc](https://forum.snapcraft.io/search?q=mozc) and [ibus](https://forum.snapcraft.io/search?q=ibus).

## Alternative solutions:

Others japanese IMEs to substitute MOZC are:

- [Anthy](https://osdn.net/projects/anthy/): `sudo apt install ibus-anthy`.
- [KKC](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-kkc): `sudo apt install ibus-kkc`.
- [SKK](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-skk): `sudo apt install ibus-skk`.

And to substitute IBUS as an input method framework (IMF) can be:

- [Fcitx](https://fcitx-im.org): `sudo apt install fcitx`.

  - you will need to install all japanese IMEs again, like:

    - `sudo apt install fcitx-mozc`.
    - `sudo apt install fictx-kkc`.
    - `sudo apt install fictx-skk`.

A list of IMF can be found in:

- [List of input methods for Unix platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_Unix_platforms)
- [Linux input method framework brief summary](https://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/2011/01/15/linux-input-method-brief-summary/)